# 設置したphpファイルをDLするとき、php処理部分を表示した状態でファイルをダウンロードされてしまう危険はありますか？

Tags: php, security

web系プログラムに関して知識が浅いので教えてください。

サーバーに設置されているファイルの中身の `<?php ～ ?>` で囲われた部分はブラウザの開発者ツールやソースコード表示画面からは自動的に非表示になり、php処理が記載されているファイルをDLしても勝手に非表示になる認識ですが、このphp処理部分が記載されている状態でDLされてしまう事はあるのでしょうか。
また、そのような場合にどのような対策を講じる必要がありますでしょうか。

追記：
少しわかった気がするので付け足します。
「PHPの配信されているサーバに入る権限が無いと不可能」
「サイト側で敢えて公開していない限りできない」
「昔、phpの脆弱性としてソースコードが見えてしまうことがあったが、大半のサイトは今現在対策済みであるはずだし、そのような本来公開していない部分に立ち入って閲覧することは仮に悪意がなくても不正アクセス禁止法違反になり犯罪になる」

上記のようなコメントを見つけました。
ということはサイト設置先のレンタルサーバーの設定で外部から見えてしまうような状態になっていない限り、原則漏洩することは無いという認識であってますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apacheなどwebサーバソフトに不具合がない限り、適切に設定されたサーバであればPHPソースが直接ダウンロードされることはありません。
しかし不具合がいつ発生するともわからないので、公開ディレクトリに置くphpファイルは最低限にするなどの予防措置を推奨します。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。非公開ディレクトリに設置したphpスクリプトを公開ディレクトリ側のphpファイルからインクルードで呼び出すことはできる感じでしょうか？何はともあれアクセス制限制御と合わせて考えてみます。ありがとうございます。